# Give docker more diskspace for containers

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I have a question. Our docker server was out of space for its containers so I gave it a bigger disk from 500GB to 1TB(its a vm) Ubuntu sees this correctily. If I do the command `vgs` I get this output:

```
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  Docker-vg   1   2   0 wz--n- 999.52g 500.00g
```

But Docker still thinks it's out of space. I have rebooted the docker VM but still he thinks it's out of space. If I use the `df -h` command this is the output:

```
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 udev                         3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        792M  8.6M  783M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/Docker--vg-root  490G  465G     0 100% /
tmpfs                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1                   472M  468M     0 100% /boot
```

As you see the docker-vg still thinks its 490gb
I don't know where to look. can someone help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to extend your logical volume and resize the filesystem to use the larger logical volume.

First, with lvextend, I'm not sure if it works with /dev/mapper. If not, you can do an `lvdisplay` to list your logical volumes:

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/Docker--vg-root
```

With ext*fs you can then run a resize:

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/Docker--vg-root
```

The command is similar for xfs:

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/Docker--vg-root
```

Answer (score -1):

With `"docker system prune"` you clean some space removing old images and other stuff.
If you want your container to be aware of the disk size change, you have to:

```
docker rmi <image>
docker pull <image>
```

Comment: If I do docker rmi it says this:     unable to delete dcc36d0c1d35 (cannot be forced) - 
    image is being used by running container

Comment: so you have to docker stop dcc36d0c1d35 in order to delete the image.